# Why does the power button blink blue on my HP Slimline Desktop

Tags: sleep, suspend

I have an HP Slimline running Vista 64bit. For months, when I'd sleep the computer, the power button would turn amber. This seemed to be the "I'm sleeping" indicator. Now -- for reasons I do not understand -- the power button blinks blue instead. The computer's behavior appear to be the same, however. I'm simply curious: why the color difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blue blinking light is due to the computer being in standby mode.  Go to the control panel power options to disable standby mode if you wish to get rid of the blue blinking button.

---

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried contacting HP about the problem?  I had this on one of my old HP Pavilions a year or two ago and the problem seemed to take care of itself after a while.  No idea what the cause was or anything.

Comment: Nate, I know this is probably "lazy", but the last time I contacted HP support I spent almost 2 hours on the phone. It ended with me taking half my computer apart. I'd prefer not to repeat that! 

For me, this problem is one of those "hmmmm, that's interesting" kinds of problems. I just wish the HP docs would indicate what the different power button colors meant, but I couldn't find them. 

C'est la vie

Comment: Oh trust me I know what their "support" is like haha.  For me, the problem lasted for like a week or two and then one day it just went back to normal.  I don't use that computer anymore.  IF nobody else has a solution or you can't figure it out, maybe like mine, time will solve it.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I got it from HP that the orange button and the blinking blue button are exactly the same thing. They would not elaborate on why you get one and not the other